# How to scrape wipo website filtering US trademarks to scrape to the bottom of every page?

Tags: web-scraping

I am trying to scrape WIPO website US trademarks. I had to scroll to bottom of the page to read in to xlsx file. I have tried using the async playwright function. But it is showing some syntax error. So, I want to write sync function to it.

This is the code:

```
def run(playwright: Playwright) -> None:

    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context()
    
    # Open new page
    page = context.new_page()
    
    # Go to WIPO global database
    print('Visit WIPO Global database')
    page.goto("https://branddb.wipo.int/branddb/en/#")
    
    # Filter US trademarks
    page.locator("text=US TM").click()
    page.locator("#source_filter a[role=\"button\"]:has-text(\"filter\")").click()
    
    
    row = 0
    for i in range(1,1001): 
    
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(str(i) + ".xlsx")
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

        await page.evaluate(async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < document.body.scrollHeight; i += 100) {
      window.scrollTo(0, i);
    }
  });
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.content(), 'lxml')
        tr = soup.findAll('tr', {'role': 'row'})
        num = 1
        img_num = 0
```

Comment: So you need to download the csv file, would it be fine if I give you a selenium solution?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I know how to download csv file present in the right bottom of the page. But it contains only 30 or 60 records. I want the information of for US it is like 10,347,596 records. If you can help me with that it will be great and I am fine with the selenium solution.